# When running babel, JSdoc for method is lost in transpiled code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jsdoc

I'm in the process of making a library more user-friendly by letting consumers see the documentation while they are using it.

I've got this script that runs on build:

```
babel src --out-dir dist --quiet
```

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
       ["es2015", { "loose": true, "modules": "commonjs"  }]
    ]
}
```

And this ES6 class with just one method:

```
const { makeRequest } = require('../../lib/api');
const commonService = require('../commonService');

/**
 * @augments commonService
 */
class bingSpellCheck extends commonService {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param {Object} obj
     * @param {string} obj.apiKey
     * @param {string} obj.endpoint
     */
    constructor(obj) {
        // code
    }

    /**
     * Perform contextual grammar and spell checking.
     * 
     * @param {Object} obj
     * @param {string} obj.parameters The parameters of the call
     * @param {string} obj.body The body
     */
    spellCheck({ parameters, body }) {
         //code
    }
}

module.exports = bingSpellCheck;
```

Transpiles to this:

```
 /**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param {Object} obj
 * @param {string} obj.apiKey
 * @param {string} obj.endpoint
 */
function bingSpellCheck(_ref) {
    var apiKey = _ref.apiKey,
        endpoint = _ref.endpoint;

    _classCallCheck(this, bingSpellCheck);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _commonService.call(this, { apiKey: apiKey, endpoint: endpoint }));

    _this.endpoints = ["api.cognitive.microsoft.com"];
    return _this;
}

   /**
     * Perform contextual grammar and spell checking.
     * 
     * @param {Object} obj
     * @param {string} obj.parameters The parameters of the call
     * @param {string} obj.body The body
     */


    bingSpellCheck.prototype.spellCheck = function spellCheck(_ref2) {
        var parameters = _ref2.parameters,
            body = _ref2.body;
```

The problem here is that documentation is lost.

[image]

However, I can see it in the source code alright?

[image]

How do I tell babel to not transform parameter `obj` to `_ref`?

Comment: Babel only does a best effort job to preserve comments. Carrying over JSDoc isn't something it aims to achieve unfortunately.

Comment: Also why does it matter? Transpiled code is not meant to be readable.

Comment: @FelixKling i want users of this library to get autocomplete while they type. I don't see how am I ever going to provide that with Babel but surely other people have had to deal with this before?