# babel renamed function param isn't matching jsdoc

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jsdoc

I have a js function:

```js
     /**
     *
     * @param {Object} obj function gets on param - an object
     * @param {Number} obj.param1 - 1st num
     * @param {Number} obj.param2 - 2nd num
     *
     * @returns {Number} - the result of the request
     */

    const myFunc = ({ param1, param2 }) => {
      return param1 * param2
    }
```

After compiling it with babel I get:

```js
     /**
     *
     * @param {Object} obj function gets on param - an object
     * @param {Number} obj.param1 - 1st num
     * @param {Number} obj.param2 - 2nd num
     *
     * @returns {Number} - the result of the request
     */

    var myFunc = (_ref) => {
      var param1 = _ref.param1,
          param2 = _ref.param2
      return param1 * param2
    }
```

At this point jsdoc is breaking because it is not connecting the jsdoc declaration to the function below anymore.

I also tried to use `@function` with `@name` but still no success.

I want to be able to see the relevant param type and comment when using the compiled version. Any idea how can I keep it consistent?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751952/when-running-babel-jsdoc-for-method-is-lost-in-transpiled-code